# Angular - test method with observable .catch block

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm newbie in RxJS world and I have a problem with unit-test for one of my method.

In my Angular componen I have a `login` method - inside I just call method from service. Method inside service returns Observable to component. Here you can see piece of code:

```
public login(username: string, password: string): void{
    this.authService.login(username, password) //this return Observable in real world
            .catch(() => {
                this.formErrors['general.error'] = true;
                return Observable.throw('error! :<');
            })
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['/someRoute']);
            });
}
```

As you can see it is very simple method (in real app it'll be a little more comlicated but is isn't important now) and now I'm trying to write a unit test (in Jasmine):

```
    it('', () => {
        authService.login.and.returnValue(Observable.throw('')); //authService is my mock
        component.login('u', 'p');
        expect(component.formErrors['general.error']).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

But I get error becauseI thrown error from `catch` section:
`login.component login  FAILED (error! :< thrown)`

What I'm doing wrong?

P.S.
I've tried to add `expect(component.login).toThrow();` but without success...

Comment: Isn't that what you expected? You throw another error after you caught the first one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe a .catch() must also throw an error. (I tend to re-throw the initial error)

Comment: @JasonSpradlin it has to return an *observable*, but not necessarily an `Observable.throw`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I re-throw error because I want to break a chain (I mean I don't want to call stuff inside `subscribe`). But because of that my unit-test fails and this is an issue

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point.  I don't know why I thought it had to re-throw.  Holdover from when I was originally learning and just started re-throwing so that I could have an early catch to handle certain HTTP responses, and a later catch to handle specific errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `component.login('u', 'p')` directly, try to have the test runner do it.

```
it('', () => {
    authService.login.and.returnValue(Observable.throw('')); //authService is my mock

    expect(component.login.bind(component, 'u', 'p')).toThrow(...);
    expect(component.formErrors['general.error']).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: the first argument of function.bind() is the context to run that method on (what will "this" be inside the method).

Comment: Thaks for this solution - it works but I'm not very enthusiastic about `bind`, `call` or `apply` methods... Is there any nicer way?

Comment: `expect(() => component.login('u', 'p')).toThrow(...);` ?

Comment: you have to pass in an function that HAS NOT RUN, but that the test runner CAN run.

Comment: I see... Thanks. I'll do it that way